# Correct way to render a form in a modal or bootbox in Yii

Tags: php, yii, modal-dialog

I'm having some trouble trying to work out how to render a form within a modal box within Yii.

Currently I have the following code, in which I've just worked in getting a link to display a modal box.

```
CHtml::link(' Email this Gift', '#', array( 

        'id' => 'giftModal',
        'onclick'=>'js:bootbox.confirm("hello world")',
            )
        );
```

I really need to render a form within the modal box. How do I do that, I have actually spent quite a while looking at how to accomplish this, but I've clearly been searching incorrectly, so would  appreciate any guidance.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put what you want into hidden div, in this case I put my form into other view for convenience.

```
    <!-- dialog contents on hidden div -->   

   <div id="modal-content" class="hide">
    <div id="modal-body">
<!-- put whatever you want to show up on bootbox here -->
    <?php
        //example
        $model = Category::model()->findByPk(1);
        $this->renderPartial('//test/child-view', array('model'=>$model)) ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then pass message into bootbox with above content

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        bootbox.confirm($('#modal-body').html());
</script>
```

When you are working with form, the button of modal box is outside your form, you have to customize a bit to make your form working properly.

Example when click button "OK" of bootbox you call submit your form by script

```
$('my-form-selector').submit();
```

**Important**: Because in this code I got HTML from hidden div, so there would have two forms (one on bootbox, one on hidden div). You have to add class `bootbox` as prefix of form element to indicate the form which you manipulate on bootbox instead (in my case, `bootbox` is just generated class by its self library and is the parent of content on modal box, `my-form-selector` could be `#form-id`, `.form-class-name`, etc)

```
 bootbox.confirm($('#modal-body').html(), function(result){
            if(result){
                console.log($('.bootbox my-form-selector').parent().parent()); //<--it should print the object of modal bootbox, it ensures the form is in modal box, not one on hidden div-->
                $('.bootbox my-form-selector').submit();
            }});
```

I think you should use `dialog` instead of `confirm`, because there you can fully customize your modal box

Comment: I was just about to edit this question as i'd decided to use the dialog and I made some progress using

http://www.yiiplayground.com/index.php?r=UiModule/jui/ziiDialog

I'm just trying to now get it to send the data to the controller/method + return validation errors + on a succesful use, close the dialog

Comment: I've not used Cjui, but it is not responsive, isn't it? If your need does not require web 'responsive', I recommend you should use Impromtu http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/. It supports many methods and event to manipulate with modal popup in my knowledge

Comment: I hadn't heard of that, it looks good. I basically have my link, that opens a modal and displays my form. I would think you could call a function on whent he 'Send' button is clicked to pass the data?

Comment: Ideally, you could submit your form by the way which I described or use ajax to handle this thing. However it seems that was out of your question's scope so far about how to do with bootbox. It's fine when you have found the way out to go ahead now.